Page break in multiColumn report
I have created multi column paginated report.
(https://i.sstatic.net/ZJ5VgemS.png)
as above i made it that group should break page between each group
but still its just breaking column.
if i change the number of column to 1 its working correct way of breaking page. If i revert back to 3 . its just breaking column like below
(https://i.sstatic.net/zdyxfH5n.png)
Any idea what can be done with exact issue?
page break instead of column
